# How to lets apache switch automatically between http and https

Tags: apache, redirect, https, virtualhost

I'm in charge of an Apache web server running some regular websites and some SSL websites. All of these websites are for company internal use. All websites are using VirtualHost directive.
So I have

```
- http://siteA.mycompany
- http://siteB.mycompany
- http://siteC.mycompany
- https://siteD.mycompany
- https://siteE.mycompany
```

All running well and smoothly but some users complain to me that they have trouble accessing these websites because sometimes they must type http and sometimes they must type https ... (Administrator's job is so hard sometimes).

I'm looking to a way that solve this job: In case of requests coming with http protocol going to a website defined as using https requests must be redirected. The same work in reverse to be executed (https to http).

Another way to explain what I'm looking for:

```
* user request http://siteD.mycompany
* but website is define as using https protocol
* user's web browser change his request to https://siteD.mycompany
* user is no more bothered anymore by the bad protocol problem
```

Is there any tips / good practice to do such job?
As there is a lot of websites concerned by this 'problem' the solution might be generic.

Comment: What happens currently when Users access `http://siteD.mycompany` ? Also, can you put VirtualHost configuration for siteD.mycompany ?

Comment: @slash When user access ' http://siteD.mycompany' as this ServerName isn't configure it fall in error, it's catch by "ErrorDocument 404" apache directive that send him to an customized error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this Wiki article [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)
You will need these rules for each of your Virtual Host Configuration. Considering an example for `https://siteD.mycompany`, you will need below Rewrite Rules to redirect Users to `https` version of your site if `http` is accessed.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
ServerName siteD.mycompany
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Applying same logic for `http://siteA.mycompany`, below rule can be used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
ServerName siteD.mycompany
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

For these rules to work you have to make sure that the virtual host configuration is accepting connections over both ports 80 and 443. Currently,there is a possibility that you have strict ports configuration because when you accessed `https://siteD.mycompany`, 404 was thrown.
Good Luck!

Comment: Your answer help me. Thanks.
I made
`<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName  mysite.mycompany.org:443
    ServerAlias mysite.mycompany.org:80
    DocumentRoot /data/www/mysite
 ...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 ...
</VirtualHost>`

this work well

Comment: @tdaget :Glad it helped! Kindly consider up voting.

Comment: Badly my reputation don't reach the minimum to be able to voteup :-/